# Find all the sets $A$ and $B$ such that $P(A \times B)=P(A)\times P(B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, computer-science

The last question in my exercise is to find all sets such that  $P(A \times B)=P(A)\times P(B)$, where $P()$ denotes the power set. But I'm not sure how to go about finding sets which satisfy the equation; what I've tried so far is looking at the elements of each set, but $P(A\times B)$ has sets of ordered pairs as elements and $P(A)\times P(B)$ has ordered pairs of sets as elements, so there are no sets which satisfy the equation; is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: We are asked to find all sets (if any at all) such that they are equal; but if they are not equal for all possible sets A, B, I'm not sure how to go about showing it apart from what I've already tried - I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to show it.

Comment: More interesting would be to find all finite sets $A,B$ such that $|\mathcal{P}(A\times B)|=|\mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(B)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $P(A)\times P(B)$ has $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ for element while $P(A\times B)$ doesn't